# error on string array while storing data with index in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem is i have an string array and i want to store data in the array with my desired index but the array with this index is not accepting the data coming from the firebase. Help me if anyone can. The data is coming from the database but the app crashes when it comes to this line "mThumbsIda[0] = getIma.toString();" Help me if anyone can.

```
            String[] mThumbsIda;
            DatabaseReference databaseReference1;
            FirebaseAuth mauth;

            if (mauth != null) {
            databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cap").child("arDet").child("rive");
            databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    String getIma = map.get("riveIma");
                    mThumbsIda[0] = getIma.toString();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your array but you have not initialized it.

```
String[] mThumbsIda = new String[10];
```

In this example 10 is the size of the array. If you need an Array with a dynamic size you should use an ArrayList instead.

Comment: Thanks, Its working now. but i need an dynamic array for a dynamic data, i'll go with the ArrayList now, Thanks a lot.